# Trouble formatting CROSS APPLY with REPLACE for fixing addresses

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace

I have a massive (government) database of addresses that went through no validation, and thus need to do some bulk find/replace for certain strings. For example I want to replace "STR" with "ST" and "AVEN" with "AVE." I want to do this with a function like the one below which I got from another website

```
-- Input: Red, Blue, Green
-- Output: RGB
SELECT 
 s.Colors
FROM
 (SELECT 'Red, Green, Blue' AS Colors) c
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(c.Colors,'Red','R') AS Colors) r
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(r.Colors,'Green','G') AS Colors) g
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(g.Colors,'Blue','B') AS Colors) b
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(b.Colors,', ','') AS Colors) s
```

Unfortunately I'm weak on my formatting knowledge, so my attempts to adapt this to this query have all failed.

```
SELECT QICISFacilities.[Programmatic ID], QICISFacilities.[Site Name], QICISFacilities.Address
FROM (SELECT QICISFacilities) c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE (c.address, 'STR','ST') AS Address);
```

I get "Syntax error in FROM request" and I have no idea what I'm doing, please help.

Comment: I doubt CROSS APPLY is recognized by Access. Why would you need it? Be careful that your Replace operation doesn't change "Armstrong Str" to "ArmSTong ST". Access is not case sensitive by default. STR = str = Str = sTR.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why the 'sample' didn't work in Access either.
And yes I was going to more specifically define it, was giving a generic example.